# overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant in Data Structure

Tags: c++, class, oop, virtual-functions

When i am trying to compile i get a strange error : "overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant", i think the problem is Node. I think that `BTree<T>::Node` is not the same as `BSTree<T>::Node`.

Base class:

```
#ifndef BINARY_TREE_H
#define BINARY_TREE_H

template < typename T >
class BTree {
protected:
    struct Node {
        T key;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node() {}
        Node(
            const T& key,
            Node* left = nullptr,
            Node* right = nullptr)
            : left(left), right(right), key(key) {}
    };
public:
    BTree();
    virtual ~BTree();
    virtual Node* search(const T& key);


private:
    Node* search(const T& key, Node* root);

private:
    Node* root;
};

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BTree<T>::search(const T& key, BTree<T>::Node* root) {

    //some code
}

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BTree<T>::search(const T& key) {
    return search(key, root);
}

#endif // BINARY_TREE_H
```

Derived class:

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H

#include "binary_tree.h"

template < typename T >
class BSTree : public BTree<T> {
protected:
    struct Node {
        T key;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node() {}
        Node(
            const T& key,
            Node* left = nullptr,
            Node* right = nullptr)
            : left(left), right(right), key(key) {}
    };
public:
    BSTree();
    ~BSTree() override;  
    Node* search(const T& key) override;

private:
    Node* search(const T& key, Node* root);

private:
    Node* root;
};

template < typename T >
typename BSTree<T>::Node* BSTree<T>::search(const T& key, BSTree<T>::Node* root) {
    //some code
}

template < typename T >
typename BSTree<T>::Node* BSTree<T>::search(const T& key) {
    return search(key, root);
}

#endif // BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
```

Comment: `#define __BINARY_TREE__` That identifier is reserved to the language implementation. You should use another header guard.

Comment: Why are you redefining `Node` in `BSTree`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `BSTree<T>` is derived from `BTree<T>`, there is no relationship between `BSTree<T>::Node` and `BTree<T>::Node`. Therefore, a pointer to the latter cannot be converted to a pointer to the former. `BTree<T>::search` returns a pointer to `BTree<T>::Node`. Therefore, any override of that function in a derived class must return a pointer which is *convertible* to `BTree<T>::Node*`.

Which, as previously established, `BSTree<T>::Node*` is not.

Really, why does `BSTree<T>::Node` exist if it does the same thing as `BTree<T>::Node`?

Comment: i can't access to BTree<T>::Node, i don't know why, that's why i write again struct Node,

Comment: "*i can't access to BTree<T>::Node*" Then you should fix *that* problem. You should ask a separate question about that, providing the exact code that fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code. Be careful add `typename` before you see `BTree<T>::Node`.

Base class:

```
#ifndef BINARY_TREE_HPP
#define BINARY_TREE_HPP

template < typename T >
class BTree {
protected:
    struct Node {
        int key;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node() {}
        Node(
            const int& key,
            Node* left = nullptr,
            Node* right = nullptr)
            : left(left), right(right), key(key) {}
    };
public:
    BTree();
    virtual ~BTree();    
    virtual Node* search(const T& key);

private:
    Node* search(const T& key, Node* root);

private:
    Node* root;
};

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BTree<T>::search(const T& key, BTree<T>::Node* root) {

    // some code
}

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BTree<T>::search(const T& key) {
    return search(key, root);
}
```

Derived class:

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_HPP
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_HPP

#include "binary_tree.hpp"

template < typename T >
class BSTree : public BTree<T> {
public:
    BSTree();
    ~BSTree() override;
    typename BTree<T>::Node* search(const T& key) override;

private:
    typename BTree<T>::Node* search(const T& key, typename BTree<T>::Node* root);

private:
    typename BTree<T>::Node* root;

};

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BSTree<T>::search(const T& key, typename BTree<T>::Node* root) {

    // some code
}

template < typename T >
typename BTree<T>::Node* BSTree<T>::search(const T& key) {
    return search(key, root);
}
```